# Merge data from three columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, merge

I would like to merge the contents of three columns into a single column. I need to use a nested if formula as the columns take precedence over each other. Example column A1 may or may not have data. If  A1 does have data then use A1 data regardless of what is in B1, or C1. If Col A1 is empty use B1 value, if B1 is also empty use C1….
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(A1<>"",A1,IF(B1<>"",B1,C1))`

Comment: Thanks... The paren placement always confounds me with Excel. This formula worked like a charm.

Comment: @JohnKenny Please finish the paperwork and mark the answer, then. That's how to say `Thank you` here. Read [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)